# How to make a database portable

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am creating a windows application with python3 and QT5.

The program accesses an SQL database through my SQL server using pyodbc.

But how do I make the application run on another computer if it doesn't have SQL server installed or allowing it to access my server over the internet as pyodbc would always try to connect to my local server.

I searched the internet for many solutions but couldn't understand those.
I created a local .sql file by exporting the database through mysql workbench but can't understand how to access it.

I am new to SQL programming but know python. Also this is my first question.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few potential approaches here, remote database access via API, remote database access via client library, and local database access.

If your application requires access to a central server, controlled by you, you could implement an [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) client using a library like [Requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) to send/receive data from the local application to your remote database. To complete this though, you'd need to set up an API through which those HTTP requests could go.

If you are using some other database hosting service like Azure, Heroku, GCP, AWS, etc, they all provide client libraries in most major languages that allow you to access your data from your programs.

If it's completely localized application that simply needs a database present to store its own data, use something like [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/index.html) which stores data in a small `.db` file in the application's directory (or wherever you choose to create it).

Comment: My application falls in the third case. Thanks!!